# Помощь с написанием MySQL-запроса

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы Table_code и  Table_form. Менять что-либо в этой "структуре" возможности нет.
Как cделать следующий sql запрос: по полю Code таблицы Table_code вывести соответственно Code, Name и список из всех F (f1...f5) и их описание из таблицы Table_forms (поля f_name, ind, date, comment, room)?

[image: Примерное содержание таблиц и результат]

Comment: не плохо бы попытки показать, потому что проблемы не вижу , например можно в лоб сделать 5 `union all` - получив таблицу вида `code|name|f` а к ней уже `left join`

Comment: спасибо за совет, но я привела лишь пример. На деле таблицы весьма объемные. Table_code содержит более 100 полей f1...f-n, в Table_form в поле f_code так же более 100 записей и их количество может меняться.

Comment: Еще раз благодарю за ответ и прошу прощения за кривую постановку вопроса. Надеюсь удастся всё реализовать по данным рекомендациям.

Comment: @Batanichek Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы (в ответах, а не комментариях) содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

Собрал комментарии в один ответ

Идею взял вот от [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13301398/5018792)

## Таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE Table_code
    (`code` int, `name` varchar(4), `f1` int, `f2` int, `f3` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table_code
    (`code` , `name` , `f1` , `f2` , `f3` )
VALUES
    (1, 'org1',1,2, 3 ),
    (2, 'org2',5,6,7),
    (3, 'org3',9,10,11),
    (4, 'org4',13,14, 15),
    (5, 'org5',17,18, 19),
    (6, 'org6',21,22, 23)
;

CREATE TABLE table_form
    (`f_code` int, `a1` varchar(4), `a2` varchar(4), `a3` varchar(4), `a4` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO table_form
    (`f_code` , `a1` , `a2`, `a3` , `a4` )
VALUES
    (1, 'aaa','aaa','aaa', 'aaa' ),
    (2, 'bbb','bbb','bbb','bbb'),
    (3, 'ccc','ccc','ccc','ccc'),
    (9, 'ddd','ddd','ddd', 'ddd')
```

## SQL

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('select code,name, '
      '''',
      COLUMN_NAME,
      ''' col, ', column_name, ' as value from Table_code'
    ) separator '  union all '
  ) INTO @sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'Table_code'
  and column_name not in ( 'code','name');

set @sql = CONCAT('select * from (',@sql,') t1 left join table_form on value=f_code where name="org1" ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21c647/1)

## Результат

```
code    name    col     value   f_code  a1  a2  a3  a4
1       org1    f1        1     1       aaa aaa aaa aaa
1       org1    f2        2     2       bbb bbb bbb bbb
1       org1    f3        3     3       ccc ccc ccc ccc
```